# Browser does not respond

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote this little piece of code to count the numbers of negative, zero, and positive elements in an array of number. When I run the code, the browser won't respond and I have to kill it! Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">
var promptArrayNum = prompt("Enter an array of numbers (Separated by comma): ");
var arrayNum1 = promptArrayNum.toString();
var arrayNum2 = [arrayNum1];
var arrayNum3 = counter(arrayNum2);
function counter(number){
    var count;
    var countNeg = 0;
    var countPos = 0;
    var countZero = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= arrayNum2.length; i++)
    {
        switch (true){
            case (arrayNum2[i] < 0): countNeg++;
                document.write("Negative elements = " + countNeg);
                break;
            case (arrayNum2[i] = 0): countZero++;
                document.write("Zero elements = " + countZero);
                break;
            case (arrayNum2[i] > 0): countPos++;
                document.write("Positive elements = " + countPos);
                break;
            default: {document.write("Array is invalid");}          
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Other than reading the answer by Amit, I will strongly suggest to give more time to learning JavaScript. Happy Learning. :)

Answer (score 1):

First off, it isn't array what you're operating on. Just split on the `,`

```
var promptArrayNum = prompt("Enter an array of numbers (Separated by comma): ");
var arr = promptArrayNum.split(",");
```

Also, your code can be more efficient as in

```
var numOf0s = arr.filter(function(e){ return e == 0 }).length,
    numberOfPositives = arr.filter(function(e){ return e > 0 }).length,
    numberOfNegatives = arr.filter(function(e){ return e < 0 }).length;
```

Comment: @PrestonTran glad to have helped. Do accept it as answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Although your algorithm is not correct. The reason of infinite loop is line

```
case (arrayNum2[i] = 0): countZero++;
```

you have used assignment operator and you are looping through arrayNum2. its size is increasing in every loop.

instead it should be

```
case (arrayNum2[i] == 0): countZero++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified working version of your code

1. use split to generate your input array
2. use if statements rather than switch
3. arrayNum2[i] = 0 is assignment, not equality comparison (use === (strict equality)
4. moved alerts outside the loop

http://jsfiddle.net/hk6uger4/2/

```
var input = prompt("Enter an array of numbers (Separated by comma): ");

var arr = input.split(',');

var count;
var countNeg = 0;
var countPos = 0;
var countZero = 0;
var i = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {

    if (arr[i] < 0) {
        countNeg++;
    }
    if (arr[i] === 0) {
        countZero++;
    }
    if (arr[i] > 0) {
        countPos++;
    }
}

alert("Negative elements = " + countNeg);
alert("Zero elements = " + countZero);
alert("Positive elements = " + countPos);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's absolutely easier to use if statement but I have to use switch as requested by my professor!

Answer (score 0):

It works now! I took me more than 2 hours to figure it out. I'm a newbie to JS.

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
var promptArrayNum = prompt("Enter an array of numbers (Separated by comma): ");
var arrayNum = promptArrayNum.toString();
var arrayData = [arrayNum];
arrayData = arrayNum.split(",");
var arrayImplement = counter(arrayData);
function counter(number){
    var count;
    var countNeg = 0;
    var countPos = 0;
    var countZero = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++){             
            switch (true){
            case (arrayData[i] < 0): countNeg++;                    
                break;
            case (arrayData[i] == 0): countZero++;                  
                break;
            case (arrayData[i] > 0): countPos++;                    
                break;
            default: {document.write("Array is invalid");}          
        }
    }
        document.write("The array of numbers entered is: " + arrayData, "<br/>");
        document.write("Negative elements = " + countNeg, "<br/>");
        document.write("Zero elements = " + countZero, "<br/>");
        document.write("Positive elements = " + countPos, "<br/>");
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

oh, weird code. Try this one:

```
var promptArrayNum = prompt("Enter an array of numbers (Separated by comma): ");
var data = promptArrayNum.split(",");
data = data.map(function(item){if(!item)return 0;else return parseInt(item.trim())});
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
var item = data[i];
if(item == 0){alert("item == 0")}
else if(item > 0) { alert("item > 0")}
else alert("item < 0")

}
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your changes and the problem with the OP's code.

Comment: Don't just answer with code. Try to tell people about the mistakes so that they can understand... that will be more helpful. For example... look at Amit's answer below.

Comment: I can do it, but I'm too lazy